# Filtering Elasticsearch Results - Nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I currently want to write a query that matches 'name', from a class called entity, then filters out the results where a guid field (stored as a string in ES) is compared to a list of string guids. If the guid stored in the Elasticsearch record matches any in the list of guids then return those results.

The code I have written to do this is:

```
        ISearchResponse<Entity> oResponse = null;

        oResponse = _client.Search<Entity>(s => s
       .Size(oReq.returnValue)
       .Query(qr => qr
            .Bool(b => b
                 .Filter(flt => flt.Terms(tms => tms.Field(fd => fd.extentUid).Terms<string>(oReq.extentUids.ToList())))
                 .Should(sh => sh
                      .Match(mt => mt.Field(fl => fl.name.ToLower()).Query(oReq.name.ToLower())))))
            .Sort(srt => srt.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score)));
```

The following code returns 0 results when I know for certain that a lot of the Elasticsearch records have a guid that matches one in the list. Can someone help?

Note: In the code I filter the records first but I have tried putting that after the .Should() and I've tried using the .PostFilter().

Thanks in advance,

Gary

Comment: Is your guid field being analyzed?

Comment: No but I have tried with that setting configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that when retrieving the extentUid field from elasticsearch it presents the string as uppercase. Even when using the code - tms.Field(fd => fd.extentUid.ToLower()) the string still remains uppercase.

SOLUTION = If the elasticsearch string is not analyzed, ensure the string(s) being passed to be compared against the Elasticsearch string field are uppercase.

Comment: `.Field(fd => fd.extentUid.ToLower())` is not the correct way to control how POCO property names are serialized to field names to send to Elasticsearch. By default, inference will camel case POCO property names when serializing but if you want to lowercase then you can use `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p.ToLower())` on `ConnectionSettings`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#camel-casing

Comment: I was actually trying to change the value of the field to lowercase but that is great to know for future reference thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would check your mapping and make sure your guid field is not analyzed. As shown in elastic search's [Finding Exact Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_query_with_text), if the field is analyzed, each group separated by a `-` will be considered a different token. A [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) says that it

> Filters documents that have fields that match any of the provided terms (not analyzed).

This means that it will not analyze the strings you provide it and query those non-analyzed strings on the specified field. If your field is analyzed, you will not get any matches.

As a side note, unless it is specified in your mapping,  your `name` field *is* probably analyzed by default. You shouldn't have to use `.ToLower()` in your match query, since [match queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) will use the default search analyzer on your queried string.

Comment: Yeah I have checked and from the start I have kept it as not analyzed, only reason I changed it once was to see what effect it would have. I can't think why I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about .Lower() was using as a precautionary measure :)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after and look at oResponse, are you getting 0 hits back inside of oResponse, or are you not making it to the breakpoint? I've had the latter happen because of my object (Entity in your case) fields not mapping correctly.

Comment: I'm getting 0 hits back unfortunately. Is it worth rewriting the filter terms query a different way? Or maybe not using terms at all and going for a different query type?

Comment: It looks like it should work to be honest. The only other thing I can think of is make sure you are actually referencing the non-analyzed field. At my work for some fields, we have subfields on fields themselves called "raw" that are not analyzed. It lets us keep the main field analyzed, yet have a non-analyzed version in case we need it. If you are doing something like this too, then change your filter field to tms.Field("extentUid.raw"). If it isn't setup like that though, then I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help! Really appreciate it. I've even resulted to removing the dashes from the string with no luck. Got to be something I'm missing.